# changed the domain in Joomla

Tags: joomla

[image]I changed the domain in Joomla, in connection with which errors began to appear in crm.
She believes that this domain is invalid. Tell me how to fix these errors?

Comment: not displaying badges, and in some cases it redirects to the old domain

Comment: i removed the link. can you pls add screenshot instead to avoid it being flagged as possible spam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Review the page at https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/misc/switch-servers/

Did the directory path change in addition?

Stuff to try:

- look at your setting.civicrm.php file for any thing that needs updating
- clear out your civicrm cache directory. typically at media/civicrm/templates_c Just get rid of everything in that directory (you can leave the .htaccess). But get rid of everything else including any subdirectories (e.g. en_US) (see above link for info)
- if you can access your administrative page check your directories and resource_url settings
- rebuild your menu's (described in above url)